# What's the average complexity of these functions?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm not sure how to calculate average complexity.

```
if (condition) {
    for (1 : n) {
        do stuff
    }
}
```

Given this function with a given condition, how do I figure out its complexity, if its condition is false 99.9999999999999% of the time; false 70%? 50%? 10%? 0.00000001%

Comment: When you have probabilities involved multiply the time the conditional would take by the chance that it's triggered.

Comment: @LorenPechtel but complexity doesn't change by any coefficients?

Comment: Yeah, the usual result is it's just constants that drop out.  Occasionally it isn't.

Comment: @LorenPechtel doesn't seem right. When are the constants not dropping out? Other than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we denote the probability of your condition by `p` (and `p > 0`), and `do stuff` is a constant time operation, then the time complexity of your algorithm will be `O(p*n) = O(n)`.

The fact that the probability you choose has no effect on the time complexity in this case may indeed cause some confusion. Naturally, if `p = 0.5`, the algorithm will run on average in half the time as if `p=1`. But big-O is a measure of the *rate* of the function's growth, and this is why constant terms do not have an effect.

However, average time complexity can get much more interesting than this. Especially if the probabilities depend on the input, it is easy to construct an example where interesting things happen. Consider the following algorithm:

```
r = a uniformly random integer from 1 to n
if (r==1) {
    for (1 : n) {
        do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, the foor loop will execute with a probability of `1/n`, so the average time complexity will be `O(1/n * n) = O(1)`. Notice that the worst-case time complexity is still `O(n)`.

For a more practical example, consider the [Quicksort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Formal_analysis). It has an average time complexity of `O(n*log(n))`, while the worst-case time complexity is `O(n^2)`. Here what affects the probabilities is the elements in the input list, rather than its length `n`.